# Fixing Unique Validation Rule Laravel 6.x

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm creating Laravel Auth Panel System(admin, student, staff) to the users table.
Then again Laravel Auth Apply for Vacancy to the vacancies table.
and Then again Laravel Auth Apply for Admission to the admissions table.
if this task is done then we need to catch all records from (admissions and vacancies) table to the users table.
Fixing Laravel 6.x Unique Validation Rule.
Giving Error is showing on the blade templating form **The cnic has been already taken.**

**Vacancies Table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('vacancies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('cnic');
            $table->string('user_role')->default('staff');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Vacancy Model**

```
class Vacancy extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $guard='vacancy';
    protected $fillable = ['cnic','password',];
    protected $table = 'vacancies';
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

**VacancyRegisterController**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'cnic' => ['bail','required', 'string', 'unique:vacancies','regex:[\d{13}]'],
            'password' => ['bail','required', 'string',],
        ]);
    }
```

**VacancyController**

```
class VacancyController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('vacancy');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'cnic';
    }

    public function login(Request $request){

        if (DB::table('vacancies')->where('cnic',$request->has('cnic'))->exists()){
            $this->validate($request,[
                'cnic' => ['bail','required','unique:vacancies', 'string','regex:[\d{13}]'],
                'password' => ['bail','required', 'string',],
            ]);
            if (Auth::guard('vacancy')->attempt(['cnic' => $request->has('cnic'),'password' => $request->has('password')])){

                return '/vacancy';
            }
        }
        elseif (DB::table('vacancies')->where('cnic',$request->has('cnic'))->doesntExist()){

            $data= new VacancyRegisterController();
            return $data->register($request);
        }
        else{

            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/login-vacancy','Auth\VacancyController@login')->name('v-login');
Route::post('/logout-vacancy','Auth\VacancyController@logout')->name('v-logout');


Route::middleware('auth')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/vacancy',function (){
        return view('vacancy.vacancy');
    })->name('staff-vacancy');
});
```

Comment: because the value of `cnic` exists in `vacancies` table.

Comment: if exists then we need to open the page and unique validation rule correctly working fine but page is not opening. so I think issues is validation rule...

Comment: what do you mean by opening the page?

Comment: if record exists then we need to open the vacancy page

Comment: and so I think issues with cnic validation rule. vacancy page is not opening... errors showing cnic has been already taken

Comment: you want the validation rule to open your browser page?

Comment: yes.. but cnic must be unique. if record exists then Open the vacancy page... also auth attempt is working fine.. only issue with validation rule.

Comment: if record doesn't exist then code properly working fine... only validation rule issue...

Comment: no I do not think you understand how validation works, if it fails it's going to redirect back with error message, if it passes, it's going to do nothing.

Comment: so why vacancy page is not opening?

Comment: is the form in `/vacancy`? url?

Comment: no, `/vacancy` is within `auth` middleware which means if not login you can not access the page, and the controller is the login method.

Comment: yes... if we change the code table migration $table->string('cnic')->unique();

Comment: then code same as error showing... the cnic has been already taken.

Comment: where you get error?

Comment: `if (DB::table('vacancies')->where('cnic',$request->has('cnic'))->exists()){` this  check is not necessary, as the validation checks this for you

Comment: if we replace the code  like this...       `if (Auth::guard('vacancy')->attempt(['cnic' => $request->has('cnic'),'password' => $request->has('password')])){
            return '/vacancy';
        }`    then same error showing on blade template form.